# Is it possible straighten (unbend) a piece of coconut shell. Steaming it or heating it?

Tags: bending, steam-bending

Is it be possible straighten a piece of coconut shell using similar techniques to bend wood?
I know it's not wood but I just can imagine cutting the coconut shell in many tiles and later straighten them. It could be a good material though.

I wonder if somebody already tried this.

Comment: I'm going to go out on as limb here and say that I think you may be in the best position to answer this just by trying it. According to some science, the shell is made up of a lot of lignin and cellulose, so it should behave _similar_ to wood. There is a tradition of making small items from the shell, but as far as making panels I feel you might be on your own!

Comment: Similar to what @jdv has said, you should just try it. Cut some small pieces with a noticeable bend and try heating them in various ways (microwave, hot pan, steam box) and see if they become flexible enough to be clamped flat. My 2c is that it should. But, if the material behaves similarly to wood you can expect that it won't stay dead flat after the clamping pressure is released, most/all bent wood exhibits 'spring back' so it is bent beyond the shape needed, then it recovers back to the actual curve required.

Comment: I'd imagine that you'd have to cut that husk into some pretty small pieces (or thin strips) to get it to straighten enough to be called "flat". At that point, it might just be easier to attach all those little pieces to a backing board that's already flat. I do strongly agree with the "give it a shot and let us know how it goes" sentiment!

Comment: Yes, it is possible one of Sri Lankan doing amazing things with coconut shells. This video about him, voice is not in English. https://youtu.be/xh5kfZqOjSk